# Does Jest reset the JSDOM document after every suite or test?

Tags: testing, jestjs, jsdom

I'm testing a couple of components that reach outside of their DOM structure when mounting and unmounting to provide specific interaction capability that wouldn't be possible otherwise.

I'm using Jest and the default JSDOM initialization to create a browser-like environment within node. I couldn't find anything in the documentation to suggest that Jest reset JSDOM after every test execution, and there's no explicit documentation on how to do that manually if that is not the case.

My question is, does Jest reset the JSDOM instance after every test, suite or does it keep a single instance of JSDOM across all test runs? If so, how can I control it?

Comment: More about this issue, and some ideas to deal with it: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1224

Answer (score 85, accepted):

To correct the (misleading) accepted answer and explicitly underline that very important bit of information from one of the previous comments:

> No. Jest **does not** clean the JSDOM document after each test run! It only clears the DOM after all tests inside an entire file are completed.

That means that **you have to manually cleanup your resources** created during a test, after every single test run. Otherwise it will cause shared state, which results in very subtle errors that can be incredibly hard to track.

The following is a very simple, yet effective method to cleanup the JSDOM after each single test inside a jest test suite:

```
describe('my test suite', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = ''; 
  });

  // your tests here ...
});
```

Comment: FWIW, I'm using this to clean up JSDOM document after each run: `document.body.innerHTML = ''; document.head.innerHTML = ''`. Works well for simple cases.

Comment: What if some tests add classes or other attributes to the `html` element? Is there any simple way to clean those up?

Comment: show me your jsdom.ts or jsdom.js file...where you created the instance

Comment: I've come to realise this when I mocked some functions from the document object, only to have those mocks persist into other tests even when I want them removed. I've did `jest.clearAllMocks(); const dom = new JSDOM(); global.document = document = dom.window.document; global.window = window = dom.window;` inside of my `beforeEach` with no luck :(

Answer (score 6):

Rico Pfaus is right, though I found that resetting the innerHTML the way he suggests was too destructive and caused tests to fail. Instead, I found selecting a specific element (by class or id) I want to remove from the document more effective.

```
describe('my test suite', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        document.querySelector(SOME CLASS OR ID).innerHTML = ''
    })
})
```

Comment: Props to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is still an issue for many people — and it's the top answer in Google — so I wanted to provide some context from the future ;)

> does it keep a single instance of JSDOM across all test runs

Yes, the `jsdom` instance remains the same across all test runs **within the same file**

> If so, how can I control it?

Long story short: you'll need to manage DOM cleanup yourself.

There is a helpful [Github issue on `facebook/jest`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1224) that provides more context and solutions. Here's a summary:

1. if you want a new `jsdom` instance then separate your tests into separate files. This is not ideal for obvious reasons...
2. you can set `.innerHTML = ''` on the HTML element as mentioned in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50800473/6586407). That will resolve most issues but the **`window` object will remain the same**. Window properties (like event listeners) can persist in subsequent tests and cause unexpected errors.
3. cleanup the `jsdom` instance between tests. [The `jsdom` cleanup function doesn't do anything magic](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global/blob/master/index.js#L41) — it's basically resetting global properties. Here's an example directly from the Github issue:

---

```js
const sideEffects = {
  document: {
    addEventListener: {
      fn: document.addEventListener,
      refs: [],
    },
    keys: Object.keys(document),
  },
  window: {
    addEventListener: {
      fn: window.addEventListener,
      refs: [],
    },
    keys: Object.keys(window),
  },
};

// Lifecycle Hooks
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
beforeAll(async () => {
  // Spy addEventListener
  ['document', 'window'].forEach(obj => {
    const fn = sideEffects[obj].addEventListener.fn;
    const refs = sideEffects[obj].addEventListener.refs;

    function addEventListenerSpy(type, listener, options) {
      // Store listener reference so it can be removed during reset
      refs.push({ type, listener, options });
      // Call original window.addEventListener
      fn(type, listener, options);
    }

    // Add to default key array to prevent removal during reset
    sideEffects[obj].keys.push('addEventListener');

    // Replace addEventListener with mock
    global[obj].addEventListener = addEventListenerSpy;
  });
});

// Reset JSDOM. This attempts to remove side effects from tests, however it does
// not reset all changes made to globals like the window and document
// objects. Tests requiring a full JSDOM reset should be stored in separate
// files, which is only way to do a complete JSDOM reset with Jest.
beforeEach(async () => {
  const rootElm = document.documentElement;

  // Remove attributes on root element
  [...rootElm.attributes].forEach(attr => rootElm.removeAttribute(attr.name));

  // Remove elements (faster than setting innerHTML)
  while (rootElm.firstChild) {
    rootElm.removeChild(rootElm.firstChild);
  }

  // Remove global listeners and keys
  ['document', 'window'].forEach(obj => {
    const refs = sideEffects[obj].addEventListener.refs;

    // Listeners
    while (refs.length) {
      const { type, listener, options } = refs.pop();
      global[obj].removeEventListener(type, listener, options);
    }

    // Keys
    Object.keys(global[obj])
      .filter(key => !sideEffects[obj].keys.includes(key))
      .forEach(key => {
        delete global[obj][key];
      });
  });

  // Restore base elements
  rootElm.innerHTML = '<head></head><body></body>';
});
```

> For those interested, this is the soft-reset I'm using in "jest.setup-tests.js" which does the following:
>
> - Removes event listeners added to `document` and `window` during tests
> - Removes keys added to `document` and `window` object during tests
> - Remove attributes on `<html>` element
> - Removes all DOM elements
> - Resets `document.documentElement` HTML to `<head></head><body></body>`
>
> — *[@jhildenbiddle](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle)*