# getByText fails if I run multiply tests but it works if I run separately

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following two tests declared as follows:

```
describe('Cart test', () => {
  ...
  const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<CartTest items={items} />);
  ...
  test('Adding items to cart.', () => {
 // empty nothing inse
  });
  test('Removing items from cart.', () => {
    getByText('Empty cart'); // it contains only this I delete all just doesn't work
  });
}
```

If I run jest -t 'Removing' the test runs just fine.
if I run jest useCar (which is the name of the file) I get the error `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Empty cart.` I'm new to testing I'm pretty sure its an easy fix. Why is that if I run the test separately it runs just fine but if I run both tests it fails to to find that element?

Comment: This is tough to debug without knowing what your `<CartTest>` component looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, what I always do in this case is to put the render of the component inside each tests. Like:

```
describe('Cart test', () => {
...
test('Adding items to cart.', () => {
// empty nothing inse
});
test('Removing items from cart.', () => {
  const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<CartTest items={items} />);
  getByText('Empty cart');
});
}
```

Or use a beforeEach function like:

```
beforeEach(() => {
 const { getByText } = render(<CartTest items={items} />);
```

});

Comment: Why? This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805128/does-jest-reset-the-jsdom-document-after-every-suite-or-test) suggests that the DOM is not torn down after each test. For tests that merely examine DOM elements -- or do *nothing* -- why should such side-effects occur?